# Angular js Parsing Json object

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs

A json object has a key lastLogin. Value of it is a string.

I am trying to print firstName **John** and **Blake**

```
$scope._users = [{
        "User": {
            "userid": "dummy",
            "lastlogin": "{\"employees\":[{\"firstName\":\"John\"},   {\"firstName\":\"Blake\"}]}",
        }
    }];
```

**[FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/xu0vqmff/)**

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Pet peeve: There are no JSON objects in JavaScript. There are objects, and there are JSON strings. `$scope._users[0]` is an example of an object (not JSON object). `$scope._users[0].User.lastlogin` is an example of a JSON string.

Comment: JavaScript is case-sensitive. lastlogin !== lastLogin.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Try like this

**View**

```
<div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
    <div ng-repeat="user in _users" ng-init="myInfo=parJson(user.User.lastlogin)">
        <div ng-repeat="emp in myInfo.employees">{{emp.firstName}}</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**Controller**

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);

function MyCtrl($scope) {
    $scope.getName = function (user) {
        return "Names";
    };

    $scope._users = [{
        "User": {
            "userid": "dummy",
                "lastlogin": "{\"employees\":[{\"firstName\":\"John\"},                   {\"firstName\":\"Blake\"}]}",
        }
    }];
    $scope.parJson = function (json) {
        return JSON.parse(json);
    }
    //console.log(JSON.parse($scope._users[0].User.lastlogin));
}
```

<kbd>[**`DEMO`**](https://jsfiddle.net/vhxg75fp/93/)</kbd>

you can also use [`angular.fromJson`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.fromJson).

Like this

```
$scope.parJson = function (json) {
   return angular.fromJson(json);
}
```

<kbd>**[`DEMO`](https://jsfiddle.net/vhxg75fp/92/)**</kbd>

Comment: Anik, why would you use JSON.parse instead of the built-in angular.fromJson?

Comment: @DanielNalbach , does it make any big difference between JSON.parse and angular.fromJson ?

Comment: Not really, angular.fromJson is just a wrapper over JSON.parse with a  string check to prevent double parsing. I thought it did more, but checked the source, and that's it.

Comment: cool, any idea how that could be bidirectional? (e.g. for form fields)

Answer (score 4):

To parse `"lastlogin": "{\"employees\":[{\"firstName\":\"John\"},   {\"firstName\":\"Blake\"}]}"` data correctly you can use

```
angular.fromJson(User.lastLogin);
```

Just make sure that you are giving inner object i.e. lastlogin to the method and it will remove all invalid characters such as \ and " from the json data.

Answer (score 0):

A simple method using angular `filter` worked for me.

Suppose, you have a variable `category` which has value `"{\"name\": \"Pankaj\" }"`. Now, I need to show the value `Pankaj` , for this I can use filters in this way.

```
<p>{{ category | nameFilter : category }}</p>
```

In filter filter -

```
var app = angular.module('userFilters', [])

.filter('nameFilter', function() {
    return function(input, total) {
        return JSON.parse(input).name;
    };
})
```

Don't forget to import this file in main `index.html` file and pass in `app.js` route.